# Improving upon the double list iteration using Guava

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, guava

Basically the question is what is the best way to transform the following code

```
for (Link updateLink : updateLinks) {
    for (Link link : project.getLinks()) {
        if(updateLink.equals(link)){
            link.setName(updateLink.getName());
            link.setLink(updateLink.getLink());
        }
    }
}
```

into more functional friendly style. The best I could figure out is to have the external loop, and use the function find to replace the second iteration and the check.

```
    for (final Link updateLink : updateLinks) {
        Link link = Iterables.find(project.getLinks(), new Predicate<Link>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Link p) {
                return p.equals(updateLink);
            }
        });

        link.setName(updateLink.getName());
        link.setLink(updateLink.getLink());
    }
```

Is it possible to write this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking for suggestions on how to use streams and lambdas to replace your iterations then you could use:

```
updateLinks.stream().forEach(updateLink -> 
    project.getLinks().stream().filter(updateLink::equals)
        .forEach(link -> {
            link.setName(updateLink.getName());
            link.setLink(updateLink.getLink());
        }));
```

I'm not sure that's any clearer than your original code.